# Refresh listview from database after a dialog

Tags: android, sql, listview

I have a list view that is being generated from a SQL database.

The user can click on one of the list items and a dialog will pop-up with the options "edit" or "delete".  The user can also hit a button on the bottom to "add" an item to the database.  All of these functions work correctly, but in order for the listview to refresh, the user needs to go back an activity and then forward again.  How do I get the listview to refresh automatically after the dialog boxes close??

Here is code:

```
    final LevelTextDatabase ltb = new LevelTextDatabase(this);
    final List<LevelText> texts = ltb.getLevelTexts(level);

    final BaseAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<LevelText>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            texts);

    final ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.levelTextList);

    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    theListView.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);

    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id)
        {
            CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[] {"edit", "delete"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditLevelText.this);
            builder.setTitle("What would you like to do?");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //user clicks edit
                    if (which == 0)
                    {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditLevelText.this);

                        alert.setTitle("Edit Criteria");
                        alert.setMessage("Edit: ");
                        final EditText input = new EditText(EditLevelText.this);
                        alert.setView(input);
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                ltb.editText(texts.get(position).getId(),
                                        String.valueOf(input.getText()));

                                //insert refresh command here????

                            }
                        });
                        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            }
                        });
                        alert.show();

                    }
                    if (which == 1) {
                        ltb.deleteText(texts.get(position).getId());

                        //this refresh works

                        texts.remove(position);
                        theAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }
            });
            builder.show();

        }
    });

}

//method for add button
public void addLevelText(View view) {

    Intent prev = getIntent();
    final int level = prev.getExtras().getInt("level");

    final LevelTextDatabase ltb = new LevelTextDatabase(this);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditLevelText.this);

    alert2.setTitle("Add Criteria");
    alert2.setMessage("Add: ");
    final EditText input = new EditText(EditLevelText.this);
    alert2.setView(input);
    alert2.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            ltb.addLevelText(new LevelText(level, String.valueOf(input.getText())));

            //insert refresh here????
        }
    });
    alert2.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        }
    });
    alert2.show();

}
```

Comment: try `theAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `onDismiss` and refresh the activity within that method.

```
public abstract void onDismiss (DialogInterface dialog) {
  finish();
  startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

Comment: this is worst way to refresh list data, user simply can use `notifyDatasetChanged` for refreshing list item.

Comment: the 'notifyDataSetChanged' doesn't work unless in 'onCreate()'

Comment: @unagi2x7: what makes you say so?

Comment: @unagi2x7 make `theAdapter` as a property of your class ( make as global, define that top of class ) then you can access that in on itemClick

Comment: theAdapter is based on the list of texts and I can't edit the list of texts from the add button method

Comment: Changed list and adapter to global variables and it works thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

make final List texts and final BaseAdapter theAdapter member of MainActivity and call
notifyDatasetChanged whenever the texts change.